# Getting a Value from empty Key in NSArray / NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I need to take out the value from the json. My json value goes like this:

```
[{"status":1,"data":[{"":558202}]}]
```

I have tried several method which were posted in stackoverflow. But I am still not getting my desire reuslt.

The nearest result I was close to was getting

```
(
558202
)
```

But I need only 558202.
I have tried

```
  NSArray *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[resultStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]options:0 error:NULL];
  NSDictionary *tableData = [jsonObject valueForKey:@"data"];
  NSString *tempData=[tableData objectForKey:@""];
```

While I do the above method I get an error:

> -[__NSArrayI objectForKey:]: unrecognized

Comment: Read the complete error. You are treating an `NSArray` like it is an `NSDictionary`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object for the key `data` is not a dictionary, it's an array containing one dictionary.

The error message does, in fact, tell you exactly that.

```
--[__NSArrayI objectForKey:] : unrecognized
     ^^^^^^^^ is a subclass of NSArray
```

You actually need

```
NSArray *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[resultStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]options:0 error:NULL];
NSArray *tableData = [[jsonObject objectAtIndex: 0] objectForKey:@"data"];
NSString *tempData=[[tableData objectAtIndex: 0] objectForKey:@""];
```

NB The reason `valueForKey:` worked on an array is because, with arrays, it actually applies `valueForKey:` to every element in the array and returns an array with all the results in.

**EDIT**

The above code can be written

```
NSString *tempData = jsonObject[0][@"data"][0][@""];
```

using modern syntax.  But as rmaddy says below, don't chain things like this because an element in a JSON collection can be any JSON compatible type, so in real life you have to check what kind of object you got e.g.

```
id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[resultStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]options:0 error:NULL];

if ([jsonObject isKindOfClass: [NSArray class]])
{
    id firstElement = jsonObject[0];      
    if ([firstElement isKindOfClass: [NSDictionary class]])
    {
        id data = firstElement[@"data"];

    // etc
    }
}
else
{
    // errror
}
```

Comment: Using the power of modern syntax, you could simply do: `NSString *tempData = jsonObject[0][@"data"][0][@""];`. But notice I said "could". Don't. Use the modern syntax but don't chain 4 accesses together. It's impossible to debug.

Comment: @rmaddy That is true.  Two reasons why I didn't do that.  1. In real life you will want to check what kind of object you receive at every step because the elements in a JSON collection can be any legal JSON type (i.e. definitely no chaining). 2. I'm not quite as familiar with modern syntax and would have had to compile it to make sure I got it right and I'm lazy.

Comment: @JeremyP Never use `someArray[0]`! if you know you're accessing the first object `[someArray firstObject]` is a much safer method.

Comment: No, in reality it is better to check whether there is anything in the array before getting it out.

Comment: thankyou @Jeremy. It worked :) . As i Know that i was getting error due treating NSArray as a NSDictionary, but also I have mentioned that by using NSArray I get the value with small bracket: like ( 234566 ). So i tried with NSDictionary method. Nevertheless, it was worth trying both method :)) Once again thanks a lot Jeremy